# Present a Transparent ViewController from the tabbar viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a tabbar with 5 viewcontrollers,In that If I click 3rd tabbar Item is like a centre Raised tabbar,If I click the 3rd tabbarItem It should open transparent view,`as like a zomato App centre plus bottom`. I search around many links.But it wont work .Any Help on this

[image]

[image]

Click on (+) button will open the view,which is transparent to previous view

Comment: Can you paste here screen shot?

Comment: All you want to do is present a transparent view controller on a tabbar? as "presentViewController"?

Comment: Presentviewcontroller I know..My issue is If we are in `Explore` tab viewcontroller and we click `plus button` then "plusviewcontroller" should be transparent to previous(ie) Explore viewcontroller) view

Comment: Hi Shangari C got solution for this issue?